# OpenTK "Invalid enum" when trying to enable Texture2D

Tags: c#, opentk

Whenever I try to enable Texture2D capability OpenGL complains about "InvalidEnum", is it enabled by default in OpenTK?

After:

```
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
```

GL.GetError() returns:

```
ErrorCode.InvalidEnum
```

[Here i try to enable Texture2D and afterwards check for OpenGL errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMtrs.png)

Comment: `GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);` is deprecated and legacy OpenGL. You have to use a compatibility profile "desktop" [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context). It is not available in OpenGL ES ore with a core profile OpenGL context. OpenTK has different namespaces for different OpenGL versions. Which OpenGL namespace do you use?

Comment: Im using OpenGL4 or OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4

Comment: I'm surprised because it works fine for me. Anyway `GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);` is deprecated. You don't need it if you're using a shader program.